# Running balance for a budget

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Figured it out myself. .......................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: you are accumulating roundoff errors. consider rounding quotients to the nearest cent.

Comment: What is column E meant to represent?  (I assume column A is remaining days until the end of the budget period, column B is current date, column C is amount spent of that day, column D is running balance.)

Comment: I did look at the example, but I am at a disadvantage because I do not have the column headers or the exact idea. Perhaps you can say a little more about what is supposed to happen?

Comment: So why from how much you could spend that day would you subtract how much you did spend?

Comment: So wouldn't the over under start at 0? It appears to start much higher?

Comment: It feels like it is giving extra credit for not spending money, when there is not in fact more money. There must be a more precise reason, but it feels like all those problems where hits at the beginning of the season move a batting average more than at the end. Anyway, I think a cleaner way to go would be to have a column for where you should be at any given day of the month (start amount)*(days left/days in month) and subtract the actual balance from that total.

Comment: Code and data in an image are useless. How are we supposed to copy/paste data from the image into an Excel workbook to try to help you figure out the issue? You expect us to retype it in order to try to solve your problem?

Comment: So I think the issue is with timing (sorry, I was way off with the rounding). If the look at the 2nd day, the person has 2100 at the beginning of the day, which means he could have spent d2/a3 that day, not d3/a3.  d3 is taken after he already spent the 40 bucks, which throws things off.

Comment: So I am suggesting way back up at the top, the better formula is =D2/A3-C3+E2, but even that is off. Because if the person can spend 19.63 per day, then after 2 days, that is 39.26, so spending 40 is 74 cents off not 56 as given by the formula.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I am starting from the top, where my first row below runs A1 to F1.

Note I introduced a column F to represent how much should have been spent by day's end. The formula in my cell F2 is `=$D$2/$A$2`, the daily budget.In F3 I have `=F2+$D$2/$A$2`. When I drag that on down, when days remaining is 1, that says 2100.

Meanwhile, I think I implemented Days Left, Date, Spent and Total as you did.

For Got to spend, I have in E3 the formula `=F3-($D$2-D3)` which represents how much should have been spent - how much was (to date). That should do it if you drag it on down.

```
Days Left    Date    Spent   Total   Got to spend     Should have spent
107       9/19/2016     0     2100    19.62616822        19.62616822
106       9/20/2016    40     2060  -0.7476635514        39.25233645
```

Comment: I would make one change (or a lot of changes, depending on how you look at it) - I would change all references to `$D$2` to be `($D$2+$C$2)` or else it won't correctly allow for spending on the first day.  (It would be easier if a row was set aside at the start of the table to show the actual budgeted amount, rather than just having the first row show what the remaining budget after the first day's spending was.)

Comment: @YowE3K that sounds like a friendly amendment to me, and I like what you did with the formatting.

Comment: A2/d2 does not look meaningful (days per dollar). The second expression should match my column f, how much one should have spent by now. Adding days to that seems strange. The units need to match. Is what you are saying that on any given day I have my 19.63 plus ( the signed difference between what I should have spent and what I did spend)/days remaining? If so column E is no longer how much off we are, but an adjusted amount for the day.

Comment: Days left until when? On the 19th of September, there are 12 days left in September (including the nineteenth), 31 of October, 30 of November, 31 of December, for a total of 104.

Comment: @YowE3K I think another way would be introduce a column for beginning of day balance and leave the current one as end of day balance. These seem to be easily confused with just the one column. The beginning of day n = end of day n-1

Comment: Personally I'm used to looking at the end of previous day and understanding that that is also beginning of current day, but I agree that many (most?) people would probably understand it better if each row could be understood by looking at it in isolation. i.e. old balance less new transactions gives new balance, with all three items shown.